# What kind of data storage should i use on my android app?

Tags: android

I am making an android app that calculates somne routes between different places in a town and returns to the user several ways to get there (by some buses, walking etc). For that, i need to store some coordinates, places names, buses so that this data can be accessed and used in the program, but cannot be modify or seen by the user. And i want somenthing that is easy to manipulate, because i'm new on this. What kind of storage should i use?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 Storages options
1.SQLite 
2.External Storage
3.Internal Storage
4.Shared Preferences

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

the link will show you examples and storage options supported by Android..
my Suggestion is Shared Pref its the most easy one.

just remember when the user clear Cache all of the Storage Options will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the route between any two places in XML or JSON format(recommended).

From JSON Object you can get 'legs' array which containts information about waypoints between two places.

Details for Different traveling modes can also be fetched by specifying 'mode' attribute.

you can use sharedpreference's to save the above details and can be used later

For more details see this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

[Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-directions-for-driving-mode-bicycling-and-walking-mode-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)  is a good tutorial which may be useful for you